# OpenRewrite: Example for MergeYaml recipe with objectIdentifyingProperty and acceptTheirs properties

Tags: openrewrite

Is there any example available for MergeYaml recipe where `acceptTheirs` and `objectIdentifyingProperty` are used.
Official [documentation](https://docs.openrewrite.org/recipes/yaml/mergeyaml) not elaborate much on these options:-

```
type: specs.openrewrite.org/v1beta/recipe
name: com.yourorg.MergeYamlExample
displayName: Merge YAML snippet example
recipeList:
  - org.openrewrite.yaml.MergeYaml:
      key: $.metadata
      yaml: labels: 
    label-one: "value-one"
      acceptTheirs: null
      objectIdentifyingProperty: name
```